# Writing into json file

Tags: python, json

I have code as below:

```
f=open(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv)>1 else sys.stdin

for msg in ais.stream.decode(f):
    print (json.dumps(msg,sort_keys=True)
```

Now I want to save it into a file using dump. How do i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
import json

# Your functionality that provides the json_object goes in here then...

with open('somefilename.json', 'w') as out:
    json.dump(json_object, out)
```

I don't really think there's much to explain here, you open the file with write capabilities and dump (`json.dump`) to it

Comment: So I am doing:
`with open('data.json','w') as out:
    for msg in ais.stream.decode(f):
        json.dump(msg,out)`
But i get error:
`dump() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: That makes no sense. Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Yes. Ok i get it now.

Comment: Did you lose the argument handling in the answer?